# What is the most Android way to get the time?

Tags: android

Is there something more in Android besides `System.currentTimeMillis()` that is geo agnostic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) and [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're looking for.

If you're looking to get the "real" clock, you can simply use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as you've suggested yourself. Based on your question, I'd think this is what you're looking for :)

If you want to get the device uptime, you can use either `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` (excluding time spent in deep sleep) or `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` (including time spent in deep sleep).